# Passing Variables OnLoad using PHP $_GET[''] With Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have an HTML, PHP and ajax application that is loading this page:
ViewOrderReports.php?order_number=77409362. I am trying to pass the order_number 
to report_action.php on load.

On ViewOrderReports.php?order_number=77409362 page I have the code below to get the 
order number:

```
<?Php
  if(isset($_GET["order_number"]))
  {
       $order_number=addslashes(strip_tags($_GET["order_number"]));
       echo $order_number;
  }
?>
<div id="order_number" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $order_number; ?>"></div>
```

Then on the ajax javascript part in the page I have this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

  load_data();

  $('#action').val("Insert");

  function load_data(page)
 {
       var action = "Load";
       var order_number = $("#order_number").val();

  $.ajax({
    url:"phptables/report_action.php",
     method:"POST",
    data:{action:action, order_number:order_number, page:page},
    success:function(data)
  {
   $('#order_table').html(data);
  alert('Current Order Number' + order_number);
  }
   });
  }

 </script>
```

Lastly, the PHP receiving the order number is below.

```
<?Php

  if(isset($_POST["action"]) == "Load"&&isset($_POST["order_number"]))
  {

      echo "Do my actions";  

  }
?>
```

The problem is the order number is no been passed to the receiving PHP. I tried debugging on the
ajax code on the sending page but seems as if the $_GET and div part is not completed loaded before the ajax onload runs on ViewOrderReports.php?order_number=77409362. Hope you can help.

Comment: How do you know that the PHP doesn't receive the number? That doesn't look correct: `isset($_POST["action"]) == "Load"`. And do `<div>`s have a `value` attribute? (I'd rather go with a `data-id` attribute). Is you `order_number` set in Javascript?

Comment: Yes, the receiving PHP does not receive the order number because the report data is not returned. I also use alert() in the main function to see if the order number is passed into the ajax. The order number is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

All i had to do was replace the div element with a input:

So :

```
<div id="order_number" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $order_number; ?>"> 
</div>
```

Becomes:

```
<input id="order_number" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order_number; ?>">
```

This solve the problem.